# Null "Sender" in WPF XAML Event

Tags: wpf, xaml, event-handling

I read here that Sender should never be null in an event handler ([Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph)'s answer to "[Best way to handle a NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812984/best-way-to-handle-a-null)").

My event handler, however, gets a null sender from WPF XAML.

This is the XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard"  CurrentTimeInvalidated="StoryboardChanged">
```

And in the main window, this is the event handerl:

```
private void StoryboardChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            #region VerifyInputs

            Validator.Verify(sender); <------------------- aborts on null
```

So, my question is:  **How should I fix my XAML so that WPF sends a non-null "sender" value?**

**Edit**: Appologies for clouding the issue with my thoughtless copy/paste of Validator.Verify. This method just checks to see whether the argument is null:

> ```
>     public static void Verify(Object theObj)
>     {
>         if (theObj == null)
>         {
>             string errMsg = "theObj is null";
>             Debug.Assert(theObj != null, errMsg);
>             throw new ApplicationException(errMsg);
>         }
>     }
> ```

---

**edit**:

Abort, Abort, Abort

Sorry. Sender was not null, e was

:(

Comment: Is Validator a system class? I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: Sorry for the ommision. Edited to add the relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue may be what your Validator class is expecting the sender to be. For the CurrentTimeInvalidated event handler, the "sender" is not a Storyboard, it will be a System.Media.Animation.Clock. If your validator verify method is expecting something else, it will be treated as #null.

(I.e. if the signature is something like Verify(object sender) and your implementation does something like "sender as Storyboard", it will end up with a null value.)

Comment: Nice idea. However, as edited, Validator.Verify just checks for null.